# Z3 C-API gets stuck

Tags: z3

I am using Z3 C-API to solve some problems that contain constraints in nonlinear integer arithmetic (NIA). I am using z3 4.0 for linux. 
When I run my program that calls Z3 C-API it gets stuck on some problems and does not produce any answer - sat, unsat or unknown. It gets stuck inside Z3_check_and_get_model() call. 
I tried running it for more than 10 mins but didn't get any answer.
The binary keeps doing some work and the CPU usage is almost 100%.

I thought that this is happening because of nonlinear constraints, but when I tried the same examples on Z3-SMT online and also with z3 linux binary with -smt2 option , it gives me sat solution with a model quickly.
The problems although in the domain of NIA are relatively simple.

I am not sure why this is happening.
Am I missing something here - perhaps some configuration setting that I need to provide to get the same performance as that with the z3 binary with -smt2 input? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Can you provide the code for reproducing the behaviour? And probably the SMT encoding also for comparison.

Comment: If your code is too big or you cannot post it, you can create a log that records all interaction between your application and Z3. To create the log, you must execute the command `Z3_bool Z3_API Z3_open_log(__in Z3_string filename);` before you execute any other Z3 command.

Comment: Are you using the new or old solver API? The old solver API is composed of the commands `Z3_assert_cnstr`, `Z3_check_and_get_model`, etc. These APIs have been deprecated. Moreover, the old API uses only one general purpose solver. The new solver API (functions starting with `Z3_solver_`) allows the user to use different solvers and reproduce any behavior obtained using the SMT 2.0 front-end.

Comment: I am using old API. The example file test_capi.c still shows examples with old API only. Is there a similar version for these examples with new APIs?

Comment: Besides, I am failing to create a log file. When I compile my program and run it, it crashes in the call Z3_open_log(). When I move my source file to z3/examples/c folder and compile it there, then it doesn't crash and creates the log file. However, this time z3 gives me a sat solution with a model as expected. Thus even though I am able to create a log file in this directory, it doesn't help.

Can you point out what is going on here?

Comment: The problem seems to be with dynamic linking.
I compiled my program statically and ran it and everything seems okay. I can create the log file and also I find a SAT solution for these examples with a Model as expected.